# Row-wide Column in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to make a row wide column in bootstrap. In the picture below you see what i want to accomplish. After that there is the source code in which I tried to I realize that.

I really would like to know what the optimal way is to solve this so the correct functionality of bootstrap is not interfered with.

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-9'>
            CONTENT A
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-9'>
            CONTENT B
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-3'>
            CONTENT C
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-9'>
       <div class="row">
           <div class='col-md-12'>
           </div>
           <div class='col-md-12'>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a row with two columns - a 9 and a 3. The left side (the class of col-md-9 has two divs inside it - each of which have content A and B. Note that divs will fill the entire width of their container - so you don't need to put them into rows individually - but you should put classes on each so you can style them accordingly. The right side has just the one div - and you can style that to fill the entire height of its container to give the layout you want. and C is the content in that div.

Also - note that Bootstrap applies padding to the divs - so you will need to factor that in as well. And that you are only targetting md sized vieports and above - meaning that on sm and xs sized screens all these rows will be displayed as full width rows.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-9'>
            <div>
                CONTENT A
            </div>
            <div>
                CONTENT B
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3'>
           <div>
            CONTENT C
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The following is a screenshot from my solution - with some css added to highlight layout. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.CONTENT_A , .CONTENT_B , .CONTENT_C {
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #bbb
}

.CONTENT_A , .CONTENT_B {
 height: 200px;
}

.CONTENT_C {
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-9 col-xs-9'>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="CONTENT_A" class='col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
            CONTENT_A
           </div>
           <div class="CONTENT_B" class='col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
           CONTENT_B
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
     <div class="CONTENT_C" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
     CONTENT_C
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by row-wide. Are you looking for nesting? There are 12 column units in a row.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   A
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   B
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            C
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/37MHUAGBcq

Answer (score 0):

[image]May Be this give you a Best Output.

```
<style>
    div
    {
        height: 50px;
    }
    .short-div
    {
        padding: 0px;
        height: 25px;
    }
</style>
```

`<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="col-md-12 short-div" style="background-color: green">
                        col-md-9</div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 short-div" style="background-color: purple">
                        col-md-9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: red;">
                    col-md-3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`